# Slow load first images masonry

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry

I'm using [masonry plugin](http://masonry.desandro.com/) in my website

My problem is that the first 20 images take a long time to load and until fully charged and remain in the left side of the page to form a column of images.

How can I speed up the first twenty images from my web page with this plugin?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can us a [CDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) or load them from a different domain. Browsers typically can transfer eight files at once per domain. Using a different domain or CDN allows you to bypass this limitation.

Comment: Thank you, the images is hosting in amazon s3. How can I use images in s3 with differents cdn? Thank you!

Comment: Maybe you asked elsewhere, but with Amazon S3, you can point Amazon's CloudFront CDN at your S3 bucket and you can create multiple CloudFront distributions pointing at it to get a few different domains and randomly pick from those.

Answer (score 4):

Along with the CDN as mentioned above or might I suggest getting smaller images. Either way, there is an `imagesLoaded` plugin that goes hand in hand with masonry that ensures the images have completely loaded before rendering the boxes.

Grab the plugin [here](https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded).

Once you've installed the plugin wrap your masonry call like so:

```
var $container = $('#container');
$container.imagesLoaded(function(){
  $container.masonry({
    itemSelector : '.item',
    columnWidth : 240
  });
});
```

Another great plugin to use with Masonry is `infinite-scroll`. Let me know if you want help setting it up as well.

Comment: Thank you I go to checking this plugin. and I notice to you that such works!

Comment: Now I am using this code but it does not works for me. Have I add imagesLoaded plugin for works masonry with imagesLoaded?. Thank you